# Performance Issues with Microsoft AdControl for Pub Center

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

Everytime I try to use an AdControl, whether any size, it seems that performance is always an issue.  Whether inside or outside a GridView, it seems to make any scrolling "jagged" where it's not as smooth without.

This is unacceptable to the UX, and especially on the Surface with a more weaker ARM processor.

Any quick fixes or hacks in order to make scrolling with an AdControl present near the page approachable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions like this aren't right for StackOverflow. These questions should be asked directly to Microsoft. My recommendation to you is to post this question to the official support forum: http://community.bingads.microsoft.com/ads/en/publisher/f/63.aspx

As for a quick fix, yes: call `MyAdd.Suspend()` when you are scrolling. But, remember, call `MyAd.Resume()` when you have stopped scrolling. Performance issues are complex, and might not have much to do with the ad control. In any case, this quick fix will help.

Comment: How does a developer know what version they are using?

Comment: By installing the latest one :P It tells you in the dll description, Mine is 6.1.0.0 atm.